# How to filter through children of array of objects and then return parent with updated children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I'm trying to filter through an array of objects it's children then update the children and return the parent with updated children.

Example array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "group1",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Mike"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Steve"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "John"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "group2",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Phill"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Joe"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Dominik"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've got an input in React where someone can type in a name of an user, then i'd like to only show the users with that name while keeping the group that they're in.

For example, if the input is 'Mike' I would like the result to be:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "group1",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Mike"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "group2",
        "users": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do that.

```js
let arr = [ { "id": 1, "name": "group1", "users": [ { "id": 1, "name": "Mike" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Steve" }, { "id": 3, "name": "John" } ] }, { "id": 2, "name": "group2", "users": [ { "id": 4, "name": "Phill" }, { "id": 5, "name": "Joe" }, { "id": 6, "name": "Dominik" } ] } ];

function filterUsers(arr, name) {
  return arr.map(obj => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      "users": obj.users.filter(user => user.name === name)
    };
  });
}

console.log(filterUsers(arr, "Mike"));
```